# Why is this program yielding this result?

Tags: java, lambda, constructor, java-8, method-reference

Lambda is used here, but when `::new` is used, the following parameters are populated into the constructor:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Lambdademo1<T> {
    T test(String s);
}

class Test {
    public static void test2(Lambdademo1<Apple> lambdademo1, String s) {
        Apple i = lambdademo1.test(s);
        System.out.println(i.getColor());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        test2(Apple::new,"hehehe");
    }
}
```

*Output:*

> hehehe

**UPDATE:**

```
class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test1((String s) -> new Integer(1), "hehehe");
        test1(Integer::new, "hehehe");  //It's wrong
        test2(Apple::new,"hehehe");
        test3(Apple1::new,"hehehe");    //Compile error
        // I think XXX::new is equivalen to new XXX() but here shoe  it's  not
    }

    public static void test1(Lambdademo1<Integer> lambdademo1, String s) {
        Integer i = lambdademo1.test(s);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void test2(Lambdademo1<Apple> lambdademo1, String s) {
        Apple i = lambdademo1.test(s);
        System.out.println(i.getColor());
    }

    public static void test3(Lambdademo1<Apple1> lambdademo1, String s) {
        Apple1 i = lambdademo1.test(s);
        System.out.println(i.getColor());
    }
}
```

The `Apple1` class:

```
class Apple1 {
    private String color;
    // getter and setter
}
```

The `Apple` class:

```
class Apple {
    private String color;

    public Apple(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Original answer

`Apple::new` can (and does) refer to a constructor `Apple(String)` because it follows the contract of `T test(String s)` - `(String string) -> new Apple(string);` or `Apple:new`

Apparently, that constructor sets the value for the `color` field since the getter returns the value you passed to the constructor.

```
test2(Apple::new,"hehehe");
```

is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(new Apple("hehehe").getColor());
```

---

### Update

Let's discuss each line in detail to make it clear.

**1.**

```
test1((String s) -> new Integer(1), "hehehe");
```

You are taking a `String s`, not using it, and returning a constant `new Integer(1)` or simply `1`.

We might rewrite it to

```
test1(s -> 1,"hehehe" );
```

**2.**

```
test1(Integer::new, "hehehe");
```

It's not wrong. It's absolutely compilable line. There is a constructor `Integer(String s)` that converts the given `String` to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Since `"hehehe"` isn't a parsable `int`, you will get a `NumberFormatException`, but that's a runtime issue.

**3.**

It's fine, and I have explained it in the original answer above.

**4.**

```
test3(Apple1::new,"hehehe");
```

You haven't defined any constructors for `Apple1`, so we have the no-arguments one by default. Since it doesn't take a `String`, we can't use it to represent `Lambdademo1#test`.

Writing a lambda will make it compile, though.

```
test3(s -> new Apple1(),"hehehe");
```

> I think `XXX::new` is equivalent to `new XXX()` but here it's not.

It depends on context. `XXX::new` always refers to **a** constructor. What constructor? We don't know it until we see the context.

Examine an example where `Apple::new` points at 3 different constructors.

```
class Apple {
    public Apple() {}
    public Apple(Integer i) {}
    public Apple(String s) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<Apple> a = Apple::new;
        Function<Integer, Apple> b = Apple::new;
        Function<String, Apple> c = Apple::new;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jwenting `Apple` doesn't have to do anything here - its constructor is just being used by other guys

Comment: @jwenting, yes, you need to define a lambda or anonymous class that complies with the interface, `Apple` itself doesn't have to implement anything

Comment: @jwenting what exactly looks weird? :)

Comment: Having a class implementing an interface depending on that same class. Reeks of circular dependency to this old brain (though I know it isn't really).

Comment: basically it becomes "public class Apple implements Demo<Apple> "

Comment: @jwenting, let's assume that initially, Apple does not implement any interface. To be a part of a lambda expression it still doesn't have to implement anything; no interfaces will be added after compilation, so your statement about `class Apple implements Demo<Apple>` is rather incorrect

Comment: Sorry,My English is poor,so I can't clear described  my question ,that's my github [link](https://github.com/AlvinYJ/Lambdademo.git) @AndrewTobilko 
Thank you for your answer，Sir